# Resizing controls in a form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have 3 controls and wanted to resize and reposition them based on what percentage increase or decrease the form `WindowWidth` property is. I came up with two formulas
One for increasing the `.width` and `.Left` properties and the other is for reducing the `.width` and `.Left` properties.
The form consists of a subform which is `anchored` to stretch down and across. All the `textboxes` are anchored to the left.
The initial size of the form is `20.5cm = 11624 twips`
The `anchored` and maximised size of the form becomes `36.01cm =  20415 twips`
These values are found using `Me.Width` and `Me.WindowWidth` properties respectively.
I want to be able to use the `Me.Width` and `Me.WindowWidth` properties to manipulate the position and width of the controls when the form gets resized.
I have the below code which works on form load but does not work if a user tries to resize using the access window. Any help or direction is highly welcome.

```
Private Sub Form_Resize()
Dim widthFactor As Double

If Me.WindowWidth = Me.Width Then
Exit Sub
widthFactor = 1 - ((Me.WindowWidth - Me.Width) / Me.WindowWidth) 'for decreasing the controls size and position

Me.txtFirst.Left = Me.txtFirst.Left * widthFactor
Me.txtSecond.Left = Me.txtSecond.Left * widthFactor
Me.txtThird.Left = Me.txtThird.Left * widthFactor

Me.txtFirst.Width = Me.txtFirst.Width * widthFactor
Me.txtSecond.Width = Me.txtSecond.Width * widthFactor
Me.txtThird.Width = Me.txtThird.Width * widthFactor

ElseIf Me.Width < Me.WindowWidth Then

widthFactor = ((Me.WindowWidth - Me.Width) / Me.Width) + 1 ' for increasing the controls size and position

Me.txtFirst.Left = Me.txtFirst.Left * widthFactor
Me.txtSecond.Left = Me.txtSecond.Left * widthFactor
Me.txtThird.Left = Me.txtThird.Left * widthFactor

Me.txtFirst.Width = Me.txtFirst.Width * widthFactor
Me.txtSecond.Width = Me.txtSecond.Width * widthFactor
Me.txtThird.Width = Me.txtThird.Width * widthFactor

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure if it's related to your bug, but is the code between `Exit Sub` and `ElseIf` intended to do anything? Or is only the `Exit Sub` meant to be under that conditional? Something isn't right.

Comment: @Mathieus Guindon I intended to stop resizing if the the condition is met i.e when the `WindowWidth` is equal to from `Width`. I may be completely wrong with this.

Comment: So have `If Me.Width > Me.WindowWidth` and remove `Exit Sub`. Code only executes if there is inequality.

Comment: @June7 I have just done that. Form loads fine but I get an `Overflow` error  along `Me.txtFirst.Left = Me.txtFirst.Left * widthFactor` when I try to resize.

Comment: So something wrong with your math. Step debug and compare values you see to what you expect. Fix the math. This isn't something I am interested in building objects to test. I am not even sure it is doable.

Comment: @June7 I see. I have tried to correct the first part of the math but it seems shrinking is a problem as controls would keep shrinking. The last part of the math seems to work though. With this in mind, I may just use the second part of the code on a form load even. Like this I could at least reposition the controls and resize them on form load. Thank you for you continuous support on here.

Comment: @June7 I have tough myself on how to properly use the anchoring feature of Access and not rely on VBA for this kind of task. Grouping the controls in cells and anchoring the cells appropriately forces the controls to move and resize accordingly.